# Need to get number of search results for a list of google searches. Was using Selenium but am now getting captcha'd. Any ideas?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a list of google searches that I need to get the number of search results for.

Ex:

"python site:https://www.stackoverflow.com"

"baseball site:https://www.mlb.com"

There are 2000 of these queries. My initial plan was to use Selenium. This worked for a few hundred, but now I'm getting just getting a page that prompts a captcha immediately, no matter how long I sleep the program.

Google has a search API, but I'm not sure there's a way to get search result numbers from it, and the free tier usage restrictions are too restrictive.

Any other options here? Surely this is possible, I just can't figure out the best strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible.

If I'm honest, Selenium seems like overkill. That's a lot of browser weight for something fairly simple. Mechanize may be a better option.

You have two options here.

1. **Use proxies**. You route the connection through a bunch of proxies, rotating them regularly (ideally, for every search, though not if this causes a significant slowdown). Only disadvantage is that Google-safe proxies can be expensive. You can always use Scrapebox to harvest some though.
2. **Use a captcha solving service**. There are plenty out there. DeathByCaptcha is one, Antigate is another, though there are many others, and they aren't particularly expensive. However, there is the real possibility that after a certain amount of scrapes, Google will see through it and block you regardless.

Personally, I'd use a combination of the two. I'd also put in some sleeping (ideally for a random amount of time) between queries to reduce the detectability.

Hope this helps!